# Replacing old data with new data using python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database

I have 2 tables TBL1 and TBL2.

`TBL1` has 2 columns `id`, `nSql`.
`TBL2` has 3 columns `date`, `custId`, `userId`.
I have 17 rows in TBL1 with id 1 to 17. Each nSql has a SQL query in it.

For example nSql for

id == 1 is: `"select date, pId as custId, tId as userId from TBL3"`
id == 2 is: `"select date, qId as custId, rId as userId from TBL4"` ...

nSql result is always same 3 columns.

Below query runs and puts data into the table TBL2. If there is already data in TBL2 for that day, I want the query to replace the data with new data.
If there is not data in TBL2, I want to put data in normal way.

For example, if I run the query in the morning and if I want to run it again in evening, I want new data to replace old data for that day, since data will be inserted into TBL2 everyday.

It is also precaution that if the data already exists (if run by coworker), I do not want duplicate data for that day.

How can I do it?

Thank you.

(I am new to python, I would appreciate if someone could explain in steps and show in the code)

```
import MySQLdb

# Open connection
con = MySQLdb.Connection(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="root", db="test")

# create a cursor object 
cur = con.cursor()

selectStatement = ("select nSql from TBL1") 
cur.execute(selectStatement)
res = cur.fetchall()
for outerrow in res:
    nSql = outerrow[0]
    cur.execute(nSql)
    reslt = cur.fetchall()

    for row in reslt:
        date = row[0]
        custId = row[1]
        userId = row[2]
        insertStatement = ("insert into TBL2( date, custId, userId) values ('%s', %d, %d)" % (date, custId, userId))
        cur.execute(insertStatement)
        con.commit()
```

Comment: Why do people not follow [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timestamp (using `datetime`) all data inserted into the table. Before inserting, delete from table where the datetime's day is today.

For MySQL, you can use function `to_days()` with day to get which day a datetime is on: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-days

When inserting new rows, `now()` will let you use the datetime value corresponding to the current time: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now

Comment: I am new to python. Can someone please put in the code. I think we can use it in 'if else' statement. 

something pseudocode like:
    if(curdate()==date on database)
    remove the database data and insert new data.
    else
    insert new data into database.

Comment: @Rio My answer is not python. It's MySQL. Please refer to the links :)